# Issue with image resizing on mobile Safari

Tags: css, safari

I have this page https://apoerin.github.io/crepes-burgers/

As you can see, all images are nicely rounded.
But on mobile Safari images from About section are displaying like this [image]

I have this on `img-container`

```
    .details .img-wrapper {
    height: auto;
    }
```

And this on `image` itself

```
.preview{
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #8281815e;
    margin: 20px auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 5px 22px -4px #000000;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 22px -4px #000000;
}
```

I tried set `width:350px` to `img-container`, and `width:100%` to `image` but it cause change of width in desktop mode in Chrome( only for 2 images of 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make `.preview` fixed height to make it square:

add:

```
.preview {
   width: 350px;
   height: 350px;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```